Fundamental group of the grid on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$
The grid on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by the set of points such that at most one coordinate is not an integer. With this in mind, e endow $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ with the product topology, where $\mathbb{R}$ carries the Euclidean topology and consider the "infinite dimensional grid"
$$X = \Big\{x\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}: (\exists k\in\mathbb{N}):(\forall i\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{k\}): x(i) \in\mathbb{Z}\Big\}$$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.
What is the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$?

Did you think through the case of a grid in $\mathbb R^4$? What group did you get in this case?

$X$ is not path-connected, and any path-connected component is a increasing union of grids in finite dimension, $\pi_1(X)$ is just going to be a free group of countably infinite rank (as for the grid in $\mathbb R^2$).

I mean, this is a simplicial graph, and $\pi_1$ of graphs are free.

@CorentinB $X$ is path connected because $X$ has the product topology you can create infinite concatenations of paths that move in one coordinate at a time.

@CorentinB: It's natural to suspect that it's a graph, but I don't think it is. The product topology is different from the weak topology. For instance, let $e_n$ be the $n$th unit vector. The sequence $(e_n)$ has no convergent subsequence in the weak topology. But $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem, so the sequence does have a convergent subsequence in the product topology. Now, it may still be an increasing union of graphs, and that may be enough to get the conclusion, but it doesn't follow immediately, I think.

It may be that, in order to think about this group, one needs to use the techniques referenced in the answers to this MSE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667035/fundamental-group-of-hawaiian-earring .

@HJRW: The sequence $(e_n)$ doesn't just have a convergent subsequence, it actually converges to $0$.

My bad, I got way too confident

Let $G_n$ be your "grid" in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 2$. Let $p_{n,n-1}:G_n\to G_{n-1}$ be the usual projection map. Then $X$ can be identified canonically with the inverse limit $\varprojlim_{n}(G_n,p_{n,n-1})$. One also has an inverse system of fundamental groups and induced homomorphisms $(\pi_1(G_n),p_{n,n-1\#})$. The limit of this system is the first Cech homotopy group $\check{\pi}_1(X)=\varprojlim_{n}(\pi_1(G_n),p_{n,n-1\#})$. The projection maps $p_n:X\to G_n$ induce a canonical homomorphism $\phi:\pi_1(X)\to \varprojlim_{n}\pi_1(G_n)$ to the shape group given by $\phi([\alpha])=([p_1\circ\alpha],[p_2\circ\alpha],[p_3\circ\alpha],\dots)$.
Since each $G_n$ is a graph, $X$ is a one-dimensional metric space (an inverse limit of 1-dimensional spaces is at most 1-dimensional). It is known that fundamental groups of one-dimensional spaces canonically embed into their shape groups by $\phi$. Hence, $\phi:\pi_1(X)\to \varprojlim_{n}\pi_1(G_n)$ is injective. In particular, $\varprojlim_{n}\pi_1(G_n)$ is an inverse limit of free groups. This tells us that $\pi_1(X)$ is residually free and locally free. Moreover, $\phi$ will allow you to distinguish any elements of $\pi_1$ at some finite level: $[\alpha]\neq [\beta]$ in $\pi_1(X)$ if and only if there exists some $n$ where $[p_n\circ\alpha]\neq [p_n\circ\beta]$ in the free group $\pi_1(G_n)$.
One can thus understand $\pi_1(X)$ as a subgroup of an inverse limit of free groups. Exactly what the image of $\phi$ is would require a little more thought but certainly I expect it to be uncountable, much like the fundamental group of Sierpinski Carpet.

It would be nice to know whether $\pi_1(X)$ is free or not.

The fundamental group of a one-dimensional metric space $X$ is free if and only if $X$ is semilocally simply connected. This one is not, so it's not free. This is why I had commented on it being residually and locally free.
